# Using dual GPU-s in a computer

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu, dual-gpu

I have a motherboard with four PCI-Express slots. However, since it was used as a server previously, it has a rather basic Graphic-card.

I came to the possession of an working Geforce 9400 GT card with 1 GB on board memory, and a 512 MB one. I want to use the 512 MB one for video output, and the 1 GB one solely for OpenCL based computing.

I am aware of STi or Crossfire. However, I do not want to run the two cards in sync, but for separate purposes.

Is that doable, given I take ample consideration for thermal issues. I couldn't find any discussion on this kind of setup in a simple google search.

Do I need any special considerations? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the card only should do ~50W according to [specifications](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-9400-gt/specifications) you probably won't have to sweat about the additional heat. At least if you have some basic case fans in place.

If you want to use them separately it depends on the application.

Comment: Explain please what you mean by "depends on the application"

Comment: Well it depends on the application and whenever it has options to allow the selection of which GPU to use.